# Remote CUDA profiling?

Tags: cuda, remote-debugging, profiling, headless

Is it possible to remotely execute a CUDA profile execution (similar to computeprof) and then bring the profile back for analysis?

The particular remote machine is headless and not-under-my-control, so no X, no Qt libraries, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. The CUDA driver has built-in profiling facilities. How to do it is discussed in the `Compute_Profiler.txt` file you will find in the `doc` directory of the toolkit, but the basic idea is something like this:

```
$ COMPUTE_PROFILE=1 COMPUTE_PROFILE_CSV=1 COMPUTE_PROFILE_LOG=log.csv COMPUTE_PROFILE_CONFIG=config.txt ./app
```

which tells the runtime to turn on profiling, use csv format output written to `log.csv`, including the profile statistics read from `config.txt`. After the app has run, the runtime will drop an output file with the raw profiling results in them. You can then use the tool of your choice to look at them. The visual profiler can be convinced open to the output, but a lot of the fancy synchronization it does requires the output to be generated using its own profile configuration files (under the hood it is dynamically doing the same thing you do manually, but on the fly). I have done some digging around and scraped copies of the configuration files so I could regenerate specific application profiling runs without the profiler on headless cluster nodes. Not too much fun, but it can be done.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with this. I don't have a Compute_Profiler.txt file in the /docs, only a Compute_Visual_Profiler_User_Guide.pdf. I can't find anything in the pdf which tells me how to do this. What do I put in the config.txt? Need a bit of help here :S

Comment: Ignore what I just said, I was looking in the NVIDIA compute visual profiler docs, not in cuda/doc

Comment: Is there a spec anywhere for what keywords can go in `config.txt`? The [forum threads](http://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/382381/cuda_profile_config-format-/#3715401) that I've found on this seem to be out of date.