# CUDA - Running NVVP on remote computer, showing results on local computer with no CUDA enabled device

Tags: cuda, terminal, profiling, remote-server

At least some of us develop our CUDA code on remote servers. And they generally provide accesses only over SSH connections. It is possible to profile a CUDA application (or kernel) with such a command on the remote computer

```
nvprof -o profile.out -s ./prog args
```

Then the "profile.out" is downloaded to local computer.

My question is, is it possible to open this file using visual profiler on a computer with no CUDA enabled device? Is there any other tool that may open such files and provide similar or richer information than Visual Profiler.

I do get such an error "Unable to locate CUDA libraries and establish connection with CUDA driver. Make sure that the CUDA and CUDA runtime libraries are on your library path. See the installation guide for more information. The Visual Profiler will exit now".

Some references:

- [Compute Visual Profiler giving error when opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645811/compute-visual-profiler-giving-error-when-opening)
- [Remote CUDA profiling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902253/remote-cuda-profiling)

Comment: If you use X forwarding (`ssh -X` or `ssh -Y`), you can profile directly on a remote machine with `nvvp`.   You do not need X running on the remote machine.  You do need X running on your local machine, but it does not have to have an NVIDIA GPU or CUDA installed.

Comment: I do profile on a remote machine without using X forwarding via using nvprof. My aim is showing the resultant profile output and getting the advices that visual profiler provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the version of nvvp shipped with CUDA 5.5, I was able to get nvvp running on a non-CUDA equiped machine to open a nvprof generated profile.

This was under Fedora 20. To get it to work I did the following:

1. Download the RUN version of CUDA 5.5 from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
2. Install the toolkit:

   ```
   sh cuda_5.5.22_linux_64.run -overide -toolkit -toolkitpath=$HOME/usr/cuda
   ```
3. Extract the driver installer:

   ```
   sh cuda_5.5.22_linux_64.run -extract=/tmp
   ```
4. Extract the driver files from the driver installer:

   ```
   cd /tmp
   sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.37.run -a -x
   ```
5. Link the driver libraries to names that nvvp will find:

   ```
   cd NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.37
   for i in *.so.319.37; do ln -s $i ${i/.319.37/.1}; done
   ```
6. Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH so nvvp will search the unpacked directory for the libraries:

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.37
   ```
7. Run nvvp and import the nvprof files.

NVVP will show the profile and it looks reasonable, but YMMV and I make no claims as to its correctness.

Comment: An easier way would be to add the cuda repository and install cuda-visual-tools. `nvvp` can then be found in /usr/local/cuda-X.X/bin. Works for me on Fedora 20.

Answer (score 4):

NVIDIA Visual Profiler cannot be ran on a system without NVIDIA GPU. We will consider introducing remote profiler in one of the future CUDA Toolkit releases.

Comment: My aim is not to profile a program, but just to show the result of a profiling.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not supported on GPU-less systems for now. Profiler has some unfortunate dependencies on driver components so it can't work on a system without the driver. We are aware of this issue.

Comment: So, it might be better to use tools like TAU in such a case? Collecting the GPU counters etc and storing them at slogs etc.. Would you suggest something else, vampirtrace?.. https://developer.nvidia.com/tau-performance-system , http://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC/posters/77_Malony_Performance_Tool_Integration_Programming.pdf , http://cscads.rice.edu/workshops/summer09/slides/performance-tools/CScADS09-Malony.pdf , https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/kb_articles/gpu-performance-tools/

Answer (score 2):

In my university we compile the code and run nvvp off a server using SSH via MobaXterm.
So even though my laptop doesn't have an NVidia graphics card I can use nvvp.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. Even though this is a solution, I was looking for a cure other than XForwarding. My main aim is being able to open resultant files of profiling at any computer anywhere, any time. I see them as files keeping statistics and thought we might not need an NVIDIA gpu to display them. Perhaps 3rd party solutions might be helpful..